# How can I trim the numbers at the end on the swift?

Tags: ios, swift, numbers, trim

I'm trying to delete numbers at the end of the string but I couldn't do that. How can I do it?

Example:

```
swift 23 
ios   36
iphone 25

swift
ios
iphone
```

but also i want to show numbers at the begin.

example:

```
25 january 2018 my question
11 september 2001
```

**UPDATE**

That's my code:

```
 func parseHTML(html: String) -> Void { 
if let doc = try? HTML(html: html, encoding: .utf8) {
var showString = String() 
for show in doc.css("ul[class^='topic'] li a"){ 
showString = show.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.decimalDigits) //it's remove whole numbers  
goster.append(showString) 
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `String.replacingOccurences(of:,with:,options:)` with a regex to only match digits at the end of your Strings.

```
let stringsWithNumbers = ["swift 23", "ios   36", "iphone 25","25 january 2018 my question","11 september 2001"]
let newStrings = stringsWithNumbers.map({$0.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\d+$", with: "", options: .regularExpression)})
print(newStrings)
```

Output:

> ["swift ", "ios   ", "iphone ", "25 january 2018 my question", "11
>   september "]

If you also want to remove the whitespaces at the end of the Strings, just change the regex to `"\\s*\\d+$"`.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

The question changed so this answer probably won't work for you now.

---

A quick approach if there is always going to be a space or more in between is:

```
var str = "swift 23"
let newString = str.split(separator: " ").first
```

Comment: I'm taking the string from array. I couldn't change the content. Sometimes last numbers will 3 digit, sometimes 2 digit. I just want to remove at the end. this won't work for me.